# For a binary classification model based on multiple continuous variable what model should be used?

Tags: python, classification, prediction, anomaly-detection

I am working on a waste water data. The data is collected every 5 min. This is the sample data.

[image]

The threshold of the individual parameters is provided. My question is what kind of models should I go for to classify it as usable or not useable and also output the anomaly because of which it is unusable (if possible since it is a combination of the variables). The column for yes/no is yet to be and will be provided to me.

The other question I have is how do I keep it running since the data is collected every 5 minutes?

Comment: It is hard to answer upfront. I would begin with carrying out some data crunching. Which columns have a correlation with the classification? Is there a linear correlation? Is there a quadratic correlation? Depending on the answer to these questions you can use a regression based model to a deep neural network based model.

Answer (score 1):

Your data and use case seem fit for a decision tree classifier. Decision trees are easy to train and interpret (which is one of your requirements, since you want to know why a given sample was classified as usable or not usable), do not require large amounts of labeled data, can be trained and used for prediction on most haedware, and are well suited for structured data with no missing values and low dimensionality. They also work well without normalizing your variables.

Scikit learn is super mature and easy to use, so you should be able to get something working without too much trouble.

As regards time, I'm not sure how you or your employee will be taking samples, so I don't know. If you will be getting and reading samples at that rate, using your model to label data should not be a problem, but I'm not sure if I understood your situation.

Note stackoverflow is aimed towards questions of the form "here's my code, how do I fix this?", and not so much towards general questions such as this. There are other stackexhange sites specially dedicated to statistics and data science. If you don't find here what you need, maybe you can try those other sites!

Comment: Thank you. I just needed a direction to start working. I was confused what classifier I could look into and there is a bit of time constraint and that is why I posted here. As for the input I am not sure either but I am planning to just put it in a loop and wait for the input maybe. Primarily I need to start working on the model first. thanks again for the help.